# Controller decides not to bind, sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not even sure how to describe this problem but it surely is odd one.
So, controller action sometimes decides not to recognize specific IEnumerable object.

Let's say this is the action I'm talking about:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Product model, IEnumerable<ProductSpec> specs)
```

Pretty simple, eh?

Here is a ProductSpec class..

```
private class ProductSpec
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public bool Whatever { get; set; }
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

What I've managed to figure out is...

Let's say there are 2 ProductSpecs in the view and user decides to delete one.
What happens then is the row with that ProductSpec becomes invisible (style="display:none;")

I know this is not preferred way of doing this but there is a reason for this.

This works fine, most of the time. Controller recognizes/binds ProductSpecs, usually.

Here is the relevant part of the view.

```
<div id="row1">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[0].Id" value="88888">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[0].Name" value="foo name">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[0].Value" value="foo value">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[0].Whatever" value="True">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[0].ProductId" value="1234">
</div>

<div id="row2" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[1].Id" value="99999">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[1].Name" value="foo name">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[1].Value" value="foo value">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[1].Whatever" value="False">
<input type="hidden" name="specs[1].ProductId" value="1234">
</div>
```

So, IEnumerable sometimes is a IEnumebrable with 2 productSpecs and sometimes in null.

I cannot figure out a pattern, why would this happen?
Any kind of direction would be appreciated.

Edit:

A bit more info:

`Request.Form.AllKeys` actually contains relevant keys, all of them. both specs[0] and specs[1] with all properties etc.

but `IEnumerable<ProductSpec> specs` is acutally null.

Cheers,
T.

Comment: Open the developer toolbar and check if the HTTP request is correct.

Comment: last input in row 2 has name `specs[0]` instead of `specs[1]`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Andrei, yes that was a typo, I've copy pasted my code and failed to correct that index. Thank you. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `ModelState` to see if there are errors?

Also - check that the integer ids of all the objects are contiguous on the incoming request.  If the value come in like this:

```
specs[0].Name
specs[2].Name
```

Or if the first is not zero:

```
specs[1].Name
specs[2].Name
```

Then binding will fail.

Beyond that, (copying a comment I've posted below), if the request is sending what appears to be valid data *always* but only binding *sometimes*, the question is whether it fails or succeeds consistently with the same data.

A good thing to do is to use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to catch a Post that either successfully binds or fails to bind, then you can copy that request to it's Request Builder (see 'Compose HTTP(s) requests' [here](http://fiddler2.com/features/web-session-manipulation)) and tweak the post contents until you can get it to work. In the process of doing that you should track down the problem. It's going to be an issue with the data, IMHO.

Comment: Andras, yes integer Ids of IEnumberable are in fact correct in the view that fails.

One more thing, `ModelState.IsValid` is in fact "False" but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)` will give you an error list if validation fails.

Comment: Hi @RédaMattar, thank you. Those errors were related to `Product model` not to `IEnumerable<ProductSpecs> specs`

Odd thing is I cannot even see "specs" in the `ModelState.Keys` collection.

Comment: What happens if you correct those errors - i.e. post a valid `ProductModel`.  Does the enumerable then bind correctly?

Comment: @AndrasZoltan those are 2 completely different entities. model with type `Product` and specs with type `IEnumerable<ProductSpecs>`. You think that by correcting validation errors in the model I would somehow help the binder to recognize "specs" correctly?

Comment: ...but even so...  what happens

Comment: @AndrasZoltan  I sincerely doubt this could be the issue since those validaiton errors were there from the get go. I could correct these but I'm afraid this would not answer my current issue.

Let me provide you with some more context on why those validation errors are there.

model `Product` entity has some very complex properties and to achieve model validity I would have to polute my current view, alot. And I'm afraid those complex properties do not have any kind of "ViewModel" (let's call it that) that would help me just achieve model's validity.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan also I do realize that this is just terrible coding practice (to ignore ModelState and such) but current timeframe does not allow me to introduce such changes. Code in the ActoinResult is already there to make sure that model "becomes" valid.

Comment: I understand.  If the request is sending valid data always but only binding sometimes, the question is whether it fails or succeeds consistently with the same data.  A good thing to do is to use Fiddler to catch a Post that either successfully binds or fails to bind, then you can copy that request to it's Request Builder and tweak the post contents until you can get it to work.  In the process of doing that you should track down the problem.  It's going to be an issue with the data, imho.  I'm copying this comment to my answer as a guide to help find the problem.